# User guest does not have permission to run DBCC checkprimaryfile (SMSS)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to attach an mdf file to a sql server using SMSS, and I got a message that says:

```
User guest does not have permission to run DBCC checkprimaryfile
```

Any clues about how can I solve that Issue? I can add more info about the details

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this post on the MSDN forums?

[User guest does not have permission to run DBCC checkprimaryfile](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e463df4c-8d26-46cf-aa2e-bddd97c7a9b8/user-guest-does-not-have-permission-to-run-dbcc-checkprimaryfile?forum=sqlgetstarted)

One possible solution proposed in that thread is to run SSMS as an administrator.

The other option is to make sure that the user account you're using to the connect to SQL Server:

- has a login setup on the instance
- has the appropriate permissions for attaching a database (`CREATE DATABASE`, `CREATE ANY DATABASE`, or `ALTER ANY DATABASE`)